# Java println weird output

Tags: java

I'm getting a weird output from running this simple java program.

The output is: 0 4 2 -6

Why does the x++ print 0, it should be printing 4.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Java1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int x = 4;
        int y = -5;

        System.out.println(x++ + " " + func(x++, y) + " " + --y);
    }

    public static int func(int work, int y) {

        int z = work + y;

        work++;

        y++;
        System.out.print(z + " ");
        return z + work + y;

    }
}
```

Comment: "it should be printing 4" what makes you think so? Did you see that `System.out.print(z + " ");` in `func`? When do you think it is invoked? What do you think is `z` value there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here is what's going on: First `x++` is evaluated, returning 4 (which is later printed) and leaving `x` at 5. Then `x++` is evaluated again, passing 5 to `func`. Then `func` is evaluated with `5` and `-5` parameters. In here `z` is `0` (`5 + (-5) = 0`) which is then printed (BEFORE the `println` in the `main` method. `func` then returns `2` (`0 + 6 + (-4)`) which is also added to the string. Finally `--y` results in `-6`. Now the `println` in the `main` method prints its string (`4 2 -6`).

Answer (score 0):

`func(x++, y)` is executed first, so `0` comes from `System.out.print(z + " ");` in `func`.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.print(z + " ");
```

is executed before

```
System.out.println(x++ + " " + func(x++, y) + " " + --y);
```

So the `0` comes from `z`, not `x`.

Answer (score 0):

I have mentioned the flow of points from 0 to 7 in the comments

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int x = 4;
        int y = -5;

        System.out.println(x++ + " " + func(x++, y) + " " + --y);
        // thus 0]4  6]2 (value returned as z) 7] localvalue of --y as -6 
    }

    //1] x++ makes x as 5 when it is passed to func()
    public static int func(int work, int y) {

        int z = work + y;
        //2] z = 5 + -5 = 0 
        work++;
        //3] work which was x as 5 is now 6
        y++;
        //4] y will be -4 now
        System.out.print(z + " ");
        return z + work + y;
        //5] z = 0 + 6 + -4 = 2 and is returned to func() caller
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Java1 
{   
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       int x = 4;
       int y = -5; 
       System.out.println("x = "+ (x++ ) +" func = "+ (func(x++, y) ) + " y = "+ --y);
    }

    public static int func(int work, int y) 
    {

        int z = work + y;// 5+-5 = 0
        work++; //6

        y++; //-4
        System.out.print("Z = " + z + " ");//0 
        return z + work + y;  //0 + 6+-4 = 2
    }
}
```

OUTPUT :

> Z = 0 x = 4 func = 2 y = -6

Here the func() is executed first and hence the value of variable z is printed as 0 and then the x++ value is printed as 4.